# How to parse angular values using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, angle

I have very little experience using regular expressions and I need to parse an angle value expressed as bearings, using regular expressions, example:

"N45°20'15.3"E"

Which represents:
45 degrees, 20 minutes with 15.3 seconds, located at the NE quadrant.

The restrictions are:

- The first character can be "N" or "S"
- The last character can be "E" or "W"
- 0 <= degrees <= 59
- 0 <= minutes <= 59
- 0 <= second < 60, this can be ommited.

Python preferably or any other language.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^([NS])([0-5]?\d)°([0-5]?\d)'(?:([0-5]?\d)(?:\.\d)?")?([EW])$
```

It matches any string that …

- **`^([NS])`**   begins with `N` or `S`
- **`([0-5]?\d)°`**   followed by a degree value, either a single digit between `0` and `9` (`\d`) or two digits with the first bewteen `0` and `5` (`[0-5]`) and the second `0` and `9`, thus between `0` and `59`, followed by `°`
- **`([0-5]?\d)'`**   followed by a minutes value (again between `0` and `59`) and `'`
- **`(?:([0-5]?\d)(?:\.\d)?")?`**   optionally followed by a seconds value and `"` sign, seconds value between `0` and `59` with an optional additional decimal point, and
- **`([EW])$`**   ends with either `E` or `W`.

If you don’t want to allow the values under ten to have preceeding zeros, change the `[0-5]` to `[1-5]`.

Comment: nice -- tighter than mine as it also checks the range of the numbers!

Comment: Good answer, for sake of "encyclopediness" it's probably worth expanding it a bit about what is what.

Answer (score 4):

A pattern you could use:

```
pat = r"^([NS])(\d+)°(\d+)'([\d.]*)\"?([EW])$"
```

one way to use it:

```
import re
r = re.compile(pat)
m = r.match(thestring)
if m is None:
  print "%r does not match!" % thestring
else:
  print "%r matches: %s" % (thestring, m.groups())
```

as you'll notice, upon a match, `m.groups()` gives you the various parts of `thestring` matching each parentheses-enclosed "group" in `pat` -- a letter that's N or S, then one or more digits for the degrees, etc. I imagine that's what you mean by "parsing" here.